# ReactJS with Keycloak login SSO: I want to login via Keycloak Login screen. without change in the browser URL

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper, keycloak-connect, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I am building a reactJs UI application. I am able to successfully login via keycloak redirection by using keycloak.json from keycloak client installation section. this redirection is working fine. no issues with that.

However, this approach does change the browser URL from "http://10.10.10.10:3000/login" to -> "http://10.10.10.10:8082/auth/".

- I dont want users to see the redirection in the browser URL.
- I am looking for a solution/configuration where users **SHOULD NOT** see the change in the browser URL, and still see the keycloak login page on the "http://10.10.10.10:3000/login". is it can be acheieve by SAML client instead of openid-connect? if yes, then what could be the configuration for SAML with my react UI application.
- I The reason for this is that: we dont want to open firewall for Keycloak from all IPs/browsers. Our VM architecuture is like that Keycloak port can only be accessible internal only.

Comment: I do not understand your requirement: is the the url change the problem or that keycloak server is not accessible from public? It should be possible to configure any server to accept requests from certain IPs only.

Comment: yes, I dont want to see the url change. I agree that keycloak ports can be opened to be accessible from public. I am looking for a solution which redirects to Keycloak login page without url change. (just see the keycloak login HTML within the actual url).

Comment: mabye you can use a proxy server with url rewriting (nginx or apache) to achieve that